# jqueryui datepicker in rails - how to link to actual db field value for existing records?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui, uidatepicker

I have a rails application that I've added jquery datepicker to a date field.
It is working ok for some uses - it appears ok, I can pick a date and it gets saved to the database ok.  The next time I visit the page (or if I check the database separately) the field has changed value correctly.

However one thing that is not working correctly is that when I click on the date field for an existing record, the calendar pop-up still has todays date/month, not the month that is actually in the database field, as in:
[image]

How can I get the pop-up to come up 'on' the month that is actually in the databse?

My view code:

```
= f.text_field :content_date, id: 'datepicker', size:10
```

My js code (public/application.js):

```
//= require jquery
// jQueryUI Date Picker:
$(function (){
        $(".datepick").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
});
```

I am running rails 3.0.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the value of the text input with javascript, and initialize the date picker with the parsed date. Try with:

```
$(function (){
    var dateInput = $("#datepicker");
    var format = 'yy-mm-dd';
    dateInput.datepicker({dateFormat: format});
    dateInput.datepicker('setDate', $.datepicker.parseDate(format, dateInput.val()));
});
```

Comment: It required two changes - I use #datepicker as the selector (my 'id' above) and it was also missing a `);` at the end which I added in case others copy and paste.  Thanks for this!